# Android Local Notification Automatic

Tags: android, notifications, push

I'm using my application GCM push notification. I can send a message to the user via php. But I want to make a push notification can operate on its own. So in practice the day if not used, the application was not used today because you get a push message. If you send me the following hours or user himself he put option is sending messages to alert the user that hour. How do I do this?

Edited:
is can be local notification ? maybe i wrote wrong ? :)

[i added this project in my app.but i need more :)](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the application to store the last used time somewhere, such as a database table.

Then create a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) and [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to fire at the desired time. The broadcast receiver checks the last used time, and creates a standard Notification if the app was not used for that day.

Comment: i found an topic about the local notification.somebody said me use the local notification u know that  ?

Comment: I only heard the term local notification for iPhone. The notification I was refereeing to is this one . [android notification link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)